# Using Google Cloud Speech to Text in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, async-await, google-cloud-functions, speech-to-text

Google Cloud Speech to Text [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries) dictates that you can access it by:

```
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize({
  config: {
    encoding: 'LINEAR16',
    sampleRateHertz: 16000,
    languageCode: 'en-US'
  },
  audio: {
    uri: `gs://${bucket}/${name}`
  }
});

const [response] = await operation.promise();

response.results.forEach(result => {
  console.log(`Transcription: ${result.alternatives[0].transcript}`);
});
```

Now, I wanna run this code in a Firebase Cloud Function. Unfortunately, Cloud Functions run on a version of Node that does not yet support `async` and `await` functions.

**Some things I've tried:**

1. Trying TypeScript, which supports `async` and `await`: Ran into a bunch of problems with some of the other APIs I'm using.
2. Upgrading all my functions to Node 8 (beta), which supports `async` and `await`: Again, ran into quite a bit of bugs from the Firebase side doing this.
3. "Translating" the code manually (is this even a thing?): I tried to treat the code to expect a promise.

That didn't work too well either, this is how it looks:

```
exports.onStorageObjectFinalize = functions.storage.object()
  .onFinalize((object) => {
  const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

  return client.longRunningRecognize({
    config: {
      encoding: 'LINEAR16',
      sampleRateHertz: 16000,
      languageCode: 'en-US'
    },
    audio: {
      uri: `gs://${object.bucket}/${object.name}`
    }
  })
  .then(r1 => {
    const [operations] = r1;

    return operations.promise();
  })
  .then(r2 => {
    const [response] = r2;

    // response.results...

    return true;
  });
});
```

**Edit:** When the above function runs, it says there's no `operations.promise()`. In fact, after taking a look at the whole `operations` object, the structure doesn't look like its the same function. I did found there's a `promise` property in `operations._callOptions`, so I tried returning `operations._callOptions.promise()` but I got a strange error: `TypeError: #<CallSettings> is not a promise at client.longRunningRecognize.then.r1`.

Did I mess the translation code up or would this never work anyways?
Any other things I can try or are TypeScript and Node 8 my only two options here?

Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What does it do that's different than what you expect?  Consider also editing the question to show the entire Cloud Function, so we can see what all is going on here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DougStevenson, I've edited it now. Appreciate you and your work.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using longRunningRecognize?  That doesn't seem to fit with the way Cloud Functions works. Try just the normal recognize instead.  I've used it just fine.  https://github.com/CodingDoug/universal-translator/blob/master/backend/functions/src/index.ts#L178

Comment: Right, it doesn't seem to fit. I'm using it because of [this page](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/how-to), actually, which says longRunningRecognize is for transcribing long audio files (1+ minutes) while recognize is for short ones (1- minutes). My files are all around 3 minutes.

Comment: If you use the new beta, the limit has been increased to 5 minutes!

Comment: @DanielValderrama It would be great if you could post your final working solution. I'm struggling with the same problem. Stack overflow is more about sharing solutions for everyone, less about individual customer support.

Comment: i jz come across same challenge. I need to translate a video/audio clip about 90mins long. The transcripts extraction took about 30mins and now i am able to complete a a short clip via cloud function. What's the best product in firebase to process a 30mins job? as to avoid browser timeout